# SetMax date to 30 days in Android Date Picker

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, android-datepicker

I'm using a Material design library for `Datepicker`. I need to set min and max date. The min date works but I am not able to get the max date which should be 30 days from the min `date(current date)`. Can anyone know how to make it work here?

```
public void show() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            PostInfo.this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
    dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);   


    dpd.setMaxDate(calendar.getInstance());


    dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this finally worked. All I had to do is call dpd.setMaxDate(now) instead of dpd.setMaxDate(now.getInstance())

```
public void show() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                PostInfo.this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );

        dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

        dpd.setMaxDate(now);

        dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");

 }
```

Comment: setMaxDate(now ) cannot be passed. as it expects only Long

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setMaxDate()`

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  // this is default system date
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());  //set min date                 // set today's date as min date
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30); // add date to 30 days later
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); //set max date
```

Comment: It says Cannot resolve method getDatePicker(). I think it's because I'm using the material design library?

Comment: @spykeburn can you do this instead? `dpd.setMaxDate()`, without `getDatePicker()`

Comment: I have tried that. It said setmaxDate(java.util.calender) in DatePickerDialog cannot be applied to (java.util.date)

Comment: Same thing - setmaxDate(java.util.calender) in DatePickerDialog cannot be applied to (long)...

Comment: one last try, back to  `dpd.setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance());`

Comment: This allows me to select only the current date. Can you tell me why have you commented "before" on 2nd line. Isn't supposed to be after current date?

Comment: have you add your current day to 30 days after using `calendar.add()`? btw i commented that wrongly

Comment: My month is zero based. So could this be the reason?